# Elastic4s: How do I get all index names from ElasticSearch?

Tags: elastic4s

I am using Elastic4s. I need to find all index names from an instance of ElasticSearch. What API shall I use?

Answer (score 2):

For **Elastic4s** version: 6.5.0. You can get all the indices using `catIndices` api provided by Elastic4s.

Here's an example:

```
val resp = client.execute {
  catIndices
}
```

You can refer the [official doc](https://github.com/sksamuel/elastic4s) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

In elastic 1.6.5 you can do,

```
val resp = client.execute {
  clusterState
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all index names and details associated with it.

```
GET _cat/indices?v
```